# Maximum File Size - supported in log4j FileAppender

Tags: file, file-io, log4j, log4j2, fileappender

I have a requirement that I need to store audit information in a **TEXT file**. I planned to write the audit information using `Apache Log4j`.

Seems to be reliable option. But, I should be able to write the Audit information **even the fileSize reaches 3GB.**

Does the `log4j` supports the fileSize even at `GigaBytes`?.

Or with a Quick Question, **What is the `MaximumFileSize` can be supported in `Log4j`.**

**NOTE :** 
I could not go for RollingFileAppender or DailyFileAppender, I need to log the information **Only in One text file**, where some other components are reading this file content and doing some process.

Comment: I have a long running job writing a 7gb log file that is snappy compressed. Uncompressed it is a 63gb log file. Opening it is a little tricky. The filesystem limit on file sizes should be your only actual hurdle in a FileAppender log. So it depends. 256 TB on some FS.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, maximum file size is `10MB`(If you don't mention explicitly). And if you define explicitly, you can define any value upto `GB`(even 1000GB). But think, when you open this file, your machine must have an equal amount of `RAM`. So you have to take this into consideration before choosing `file size`.
An example here

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100GB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

`FileAppender` doesn't contain any field for setting file size. But its subclasses `RollingFileAppender` and `DailyFileAppender` contains.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As you mentioned, which property(field) in Log4j FileAppender holds this maximumFileSize value?. Will that datatype of the field holds these big value?.

Comment: Accepting your point as to open file should be supported with RAM size. But, still confused with how this size value is binded within FileAppender.

Comment: I think, you should go for `database logging`. Actually, `FileAppender` doesn't contain any such field for size. But their subclasses `RollingFileAppender` and `DailyFileAppender` contains. More, you can refer [link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: Is there an inherit negative consequence of size limiting a single log file? It seems like once the limit is reached it would have to be actively managing the size every time the file is written to.

Comment: You CAN open a file that's bigger than your memory if you use a tool that doesn't load the whole file just to show you whatever lines fit on the screen. There are many, but vi does, and https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/large-file-support/files-up-to-248gb/