# How to increase or set MaxFileSize in DailyRollingFileAppender in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, log4j

In my application logfile will Rollover every hour ,but the logfile is not able to handle or store more than 1000MB(approximately) size .How can I increase the size of logfile to more than 5GB??

Here is my log4j.xml

```
<appender name="DailyLogFile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="./application.log" /> 
         <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />

     <param name="DatePattern" value="'.Hourly_'yyyy_MM_dd_HH" /> 
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="fileNamePattern" value="./application_%d{ddMMMyyyy HH}**.gz**" />
            <param name="rollOver" value="TRUE" />
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender> 
    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="DailyLogFile" />
    </root>
```

Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: Have you checked 1000 MB is not the limit on your filesystem?

Comment: I checked it is not the limit some files in GB's are present

Comment: This may be [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083450/maximum-file-size-supported-in-log4j-fileappender)

Comment: I need to Roll log file every hour and how that functionality is achieved in RollingFileAppender???