# Set max filesize for Java Trace Logging

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

i want to increase the max output filesize for Java logging files from 10MB to a higher value. I used the *slf4j* logging technique

i tried

```
deployment.max.file.size=30
```

in deployment.properties, without any effects. How it is possible without edit the sourcecode?

Thanks

Comment: Which logging framework are you using with slf4j? log4j? commons logging? Configuration should depend on this. And where did you put the property - do the other configurations work?

Comment: I use the simpeLogger with Log4j

Comment: so you should regard  log4j configuration, which is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083450/maximum-file-size-supported-in-log4j-fileappender?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa